# Populate OutputBuffer from a List in PostExecute using C# transformer

Tags: c#, ssis

The saga of trying to chop flat files up into useable bits continues!

You may see from my other questions that I am trying to wrangle some flat file data into various bits using C# transformer in SSIS. The current challenge is trying to turn a selection of rows with one column into one row with many columns.

A friend has very kindly tipped me off to use List and then to somehow loop through that in the PostExecute().

The main problem is that I do not know how to loop through and create a row to add to the Output Buffer programatically - there might be a variable number of fields listed in the flat file, there is no consistency. For now, I have allowed for 100 outputs and called these pos1, pos2, etc.

What I would really like to do is count everything in my list, and loop through that many times, incrementing the numbers accordingly - i.e. fieldlist[0] goes to OutputBuffer.pos1, fieldlist[1] goes to OutputBuffer.pos2, and if there is nothing after this then nothing is put in pos3 to pos100.

The secondary problem is that I can't even test that my list and writing to an output table is working by specifically using OutputBuffer in PostExecute, never mind working out a loop.

The file has all sorts in it, but the list of fields is handily contained between START-OF-FIELDS and END-OF-FIELDS, so I have used the same logic as before to only process the rows in the middle of those.

```
bool passedSOF;
bool passedEOF;

List<string> fieldlist = new List<string>();

public override void PostExecute()
{
base.PostExecute();

OutputBuffer.AddRow();
OutputBuffer.field1=fieldlist[0];
OutputBuffer.field2=fieldlist[1];
}

public override void Input_ProcessInputRow(InputBuffer Row)
{
if (Row.RawData.Contains("END-OF-FIELDS"))
{
passedEOF = true;
OutputBuffer.SetEndOfRowset();
}

if (passedSOF && !passedEOF)
{
fieldlist.Add(Row.RawData);
}

if(Row.RawData.Contains("START-OF-FIELDS"))
{
passedSOF = true;
}
}
```

I have nothing underlined in red, but when I try to run this I get an error message about PostExecute() and "object reference not set to an instance of an object", which I thought meant something contained a null where it shouldn't, but in my test file I have more than two fields between START and END markers.

So first of all, what am I doing wrong in the example above, and secondly, how do I do this in a proper loop? There are only 100 possible outputs right now, but this could increase over time.

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but you might want this to be a source and not a transform.

Comment: and the error is always object refencence... from SSIS perspective. You will geta better error if you add a breakpoint.

Comment: what's in your list? Actually post your source and what you are trying to extract out of it.

Comment: The source has several header rows, then a row with START-OF-FIELDS, then a number of rows with field names, like FRUIT, DAIRY, STARCHES. There is an END-OF-FIELDS, then some more stuff I'm not using for this part. Apparently I can't use OutputBuffer where I am trying to use it - going to post up a solution someone much smarter than me found tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So once again I have misunderstood a basic concept - PostExecute cannot be used to write out in the way I was trying. As people have pointed out, there is no way to do anything with the buffer contents here.

I cannot take credit for this answer, as again someone smarter than me came to the rescue, but I have got permission from them to post the code in case it is useful to anyone. I hope I have explained this OK, as I only just understand it myself and am very much learning as I go along.

First of all, make sure to have the following in your namespace:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

These are going to be used to get properties for the Output Buffer and to allow me to output the first item in the list to pos_1, the second to pos_2, etc.

As usual I have two boolean variables to determine if I have passed the row which indicates the rows of data I want have started or ended, and I have my List.

```
bool passedSOF;
bool passedEOF;

List<string> fieldlist = new List<string>();
```

Here is where it is different - as I have something which indicates I am done processing my rows, which is the row containing END-OF-FIELDS, when I hit that point, I should be writing out my collected List to my output buffer. The aim is to take all of the multiple rows containing field names, and turn that into a single row with multiple columns, with the field names populated across those columns in the row order they appeared.

```
if (Row.RawData.Contains("END-OF-FIELDS"))
{
passedEOF = true;

//IF WE HAVE GOT TO THIS POINT, WE HAVE ALL THE DATA IN OUR LIST NOW
OutputBuffer.AddRow();

var fields = typeof(OutputBuffer).GetProperties();

//SET UP AND INITIALISE A VARIABLE TO HOLD THE ROW NUMBER COUNT
int rowNumber = 0;

foreach (var fieldName in fieldList)
{
//ADD ONE TO THE CURRENT VALUE OF rowNumber
rowNumber++;

//MATCH THE ROW NUMBER TO THE OUTPUT FIELD NAME
PropertyInfo field = fields.FirstOrDefault(x = > x.Name == string.Format("pos{0}", rowNumber));

if (field != null)
{
field.SetValue(OutputBuffer, fieldName);
}
}
OutputBuffer.SetEndOfRowset();
}

if (passedSOF && !passedEOF)
{
this.fieldList.Add(Row.RawData);
}

if (Row.RawData.Contains("START-OF-FIELDS"))
{
passedSOF = true;
}
```

So instead of having something like this:

- START-OF-FIELDS
- FRUIT
- DAIRY
- STARCHES
- END-OF-FIELDS

I have the output:

pos_1 | pos_2 | pos_3

FRUIT | DAIRY | STARCHES

So I can build a position key table to show which field will appear in which order in the current monthly file, and now I am looking forward into getting myself into more trouble splitting the actual data rows out into another table :)

Answer (score 0):

"Post execute" It's named that for a reason.

The execution of your data flow has ended and this method is for cleanup or anything that needs to happen after execution - like modification of SSIS variables. The buffers have gone away, there's no way to do interact with the contents of the buffers at this point.

As for the rest of your problem statement... it needs focus

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by needs focus - do you mean I didn't explain it clearly enough? If that's the case please accept my apologies, I am new both to C#, SSIS, and posting in forums.